# Ubuntu 20.04 PC not giving print on cannon printer imageClass LBP7100Cn?

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

we are facing problem when we give print to canon imageClass LBP7100Cn after installing printer driver "linux-UFRII-drv-v500-uken-18.tar.gz" from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS PC. Though Printer Driver for linux install successfully yet printer was not coming on printer.

We found some logs in Ubuntu 20.04 during analyzing this problem. (These logs are generated at the time of print given):

E [02/Feb/2021:08:37:05 +0530] [Job 67] src = libcanon_pdlwrapper.c, line = 633, err = -1¥nERROR: src = libcanon_pdlwrapper.c, line = 345, err = 0¥nfree(): invalid pointer
W [02/Feb/2021:09:04:53 +0530] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'LBP7100C-7110C-Gray..' already exists
W [02/Feb/2021:09:04:53 +0530] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'LBP7100C-7110C-RGB..' already exists
W [02/Feb/2021:09:04:54 +0530] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'Canon-LBP7100C-7110C-Gray..' already exists
W [02/Feb/2021:09:04:54 +0530] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'Canon-LBP7100C-7110C-RGB..' already exists
E [02/Feb/2021:09:05:34 +0530] [Job 68] src = libcanon_pdlwrapper.c, line = 633, err = -1¥nERROR: src = libcanon_pdlwrapper.c, line = 345, err = 0¥nfree(): invalid pointer
E [02/Feb/2021:09:08:25 +0530] [Job 69] src = libcanon_pdlwrapper.c, line = 633, err = -1¥nERROR: src = libcanon_pdlwrapper.c, line = 345, err = 0¥nfree(): invalid pointer
E [02/Feb/2021:13:21:14 +0530] [Job 71] src = libcanon_pdlwrapper.c, line = 633, err = -1¥nERROR: src = libcanon_pdlwrapper.c, line = 345, err = 0¥nfree(): invalid pointer

Answer (score 0):

Linux Canon LBP7100Cn Driver

Goto this page , https://in.canon/en/support/0100595001

Download Tarball
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v500-uken-18.tar.gz

open up in archive viewer , goto Driver 64 bit / Debian / and extract the driver file .

cnrdrvcups-ufr2lt-uk_5.00-1_amd64.deb

install this driver file using the software app , I have Ubuntu Studio 20 64bit

Add new printer ( delete your old driver ) , in my case search network printer , select and go . simple , though it did take some investigation .

good luck !